# How to log into Jupyter notebook's console instead of webpage after version 4.1.1

Tags: python, logging, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

In version 4.1.0:

```
import logging
r = logging.getLogger()
r.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("debug")
```

will log into the console/terminal.
And we can get a default `StreamHandler` by:
`stream_handler = root.handlers[0]`

But in 4.1.1, the handler is missing and the code above will log to the webpage.

I can not find the release note or changelog of 4.1.1.

How can I log into console in the latest version of jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is add the standard output unit by myself.

```
root = logging.getLogger()
root.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(os.fdopen(1, "w")))
```

now, `logging.debug` log into the console

Comment: Note that this will not work with unicode error messages.  For example: something like this `logging.error("(ヒラギノ明朝 ProN.ttc)")` will raise an error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-6: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Comment: A solution may be to specify the encoding  `root.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(open(1, "w", encoding="utf-8")))`